# How to fetch youtube video data using php?

Tags: php, xml, youtube

I need to get the XML data from youtube for a particular video(based on ID) and fetch the thumbnail url. I am using PHP. 
The code is as follows:

```
<?php

//$xmlFilePath = 'http://localhost/testFile.xml'; //This works..
$xmlFilePath = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5P6UU6m3cqk?v=2';

$dataFromYoutube = file_get_contents($xmlFilePath);
print_r($dataFromYoutube);
?>
```

I dont get any data. The output is blank. If I load the url 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5P6UU6m3cqk?v=2' in browser and copy the content to a file(http://localhost/testFile.xml), then the above code works.
I have tried fetching the youtube data using ajax and also simlexml_load_file function in php. But the result is blank/empty for Youtube url. However, I get the data for 'http://localhost/testFile.xml' in both cases.
How can I fetch youtube data using php?

Please help.

Comment: You probably need to specify some request headers like the user-agent or referrer. Pleae use the search here on the site, I guess your question has been asked earlier.

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work for you, but one possibility for a solution is to replace the `https` with `http`.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Could there be any issue with the network setting(proxy etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

well, your code is correct and works fine too. It may be that your apache server is not configured for "https". So just check it once too.